# How can we do a Trialforce duplicate username check, before generating a Trial for customer?

Tags: duplicate-management, trialforce, registration

Can we leverage anything from platform in detecting a duplicate username before hand for Trialforce registered customer orgs?

The practice currently being followed is, user fills in the info (username, email etc) and submits. After submission he could only be informed about the unsuccessful trial with a generic message that something went wrong. And most of the time (well always usually) it is due to duplicate username selected on the form.

While when we generate an Org from a url like this:
https://developer.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial.jsp

We get notified of a duplicate username before we could submit the form. I would really like an approach or api call interface like that for trialforce forms. Is there anything available to handle that?